# Replace a particular text from a CSV file without knowing the text

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, text

I need to replace a particular value from a text file, without knowing the value of the string to be replaced. All I know is the line number, and the location of the value in that line which has to be replaced. This has to be done using Python 2.7

for example, the file is like this:

```
a,b,c,s,d,f
s,d,f,g,d,f
a,d,s,f,g,r
a,s,d,f,e,c
```

My code goes like this:

```
point_file = open(pointfile,'r+')
read_lines = point_file.readlines()
arr1 = []
for i in range(len(read_lines)):
    arr1.append(read_lines[i])
```

Now I need to replace

```
arr1[3].split(',')[3]
```

How to do that?

**Edit**

I do not wish to achieve this using a temporary copy file and then overwrite the existing file. I need to edit the value **in place** the **existing** file.

Comment: What exactly is the "location of the value"? Is is a column number, a field number (and in that case, how are lines formatted)?

Comment: Looks like a homework. Show us what you have tried and we may help on that particular point. Hint: read the file line by line so you can find the specific line (:

Comment: I've edited the question, please have a look

Comment: you want to replace the `f` on the bottom row?

Comment: Nopes, exactly at the same place

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I'm assuming fields can have any value (or the following can be shortened considerably by clever substitution tricks).

```
from __future__ import print_function

target = (3, 3) # Coordinates of the replaced value
new_val = 'X'   # New value for the replaced cells
with open('src.txt') as f_src:
    data = f_src.read().strip()

table = [line.split(',') for line in data.split('\n')]
old_val = table[target[0]][target[1]]
new_data = '\n'.join(
                ','.join(
                    new_val if cell == old_val else cell
                    for cell in row)
                for row in table)

with open('tgt.txt', 'w') as f_tgt:
    print(new_data, file=f_tgt)
```

My test `src.txt`:

```
a,b,c,s,d,f
s,d,f,g,d,f
a,d,s,f,g,r
a,s,d,f,e,c
```

My output `tgt.txt`:

```
a,b,c,s,d,X
s,d,X,g,d,X
a,d,s,X,g,r
a,s,d,X,e,c
```

Comment: Here you are making a duplicate file, where as I would prefer the output to be in the same file, so basically I am looking for a method to directly edit the file which I have already opened..!

Comment: Well, you can also write in the source file, and the original contents will be replaced. Unless you have issues with opening the same file twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. Read the data as a `csv` file and turn it into a list of lists. You can then alter the value at the required index `[3][3]` and write back to another `csv`.

```
import csv

with open('indata.csv') as f:
    lines = [line for line in csv.reader(f)]

# change the required value
lines[3][3] = 'X'

with open('outdata.csv', 'w') as fout:
    csv.writer(fout).writerows(lines)
```

Comment: Here you are making a duplicate file, where as I would prefer the output to be in the same file, so basically I am looking for a method to directly edit the file which I have already opened..!

Comment: @VivianjeetSinghSudan just use the same file name in the second `open`. The file should be closed from the first open by then.

Answer (score 0):

[Solved] Turns out that one cannot edit one particular instance of the file without over writing the whole file. This could be memory intensive in cases where I have a lot of data to be saved in the same file. So, i replaces saving data in file with saving data in an array.